# Solution to avoid blank places on screen resize css or jquery

Tags: jquery, css, autoresize

The situaliton: 
We have 16 div blocks on the screen with `float:left` property.

```
# # # #
# # # #
# # # #
# # # #
```

After screen resizing, (ie. reduction on this example) we get this:

```
# # # 
# # # 
# # #
# # #
# # #
# x x
```

where `x` - is blank places.

So, I need some css or jquery solution to avoid blank places if they appear after screen resize or on load.

Maybe to show some hidden divs pre-cooked or one div that will cover two or more places automaticaly.

emaple http://jsfiddle.net/ekPsL/

Comment: If you can resize div blocks, use media queries to do it.

Comment: make a fiddle or post your code ..

Comment: What have you tried? The above example looks like simple maths would provide the n number of placeholder elements to insert into the DOM.

Comment: div block size is fixed. (they contain thumbs)

Comment: @abrahab You can increase the width and height of each thumb so that each line has two thumbs

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ekPsL/ exaple @TusharGupta